# Unable to resume after suspend (snd_hda_intel: Unable to change power state)

Tags: drivers, suspend, hda-intel

My computer no longer completes the resume process after suspend. As far as I can tell it's  an issue with the Intel HDA driver, but I have no idea how to resolve the problem.

---

Specs

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Acer Aspire A715-72G
- Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz × 12
- NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]

---

The symptom. When resuming, the black screen with a blinking cursor appears as normal, but it has two messages and never continues past the message screen.

Messages:

```
[#####.######] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[#####.######] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: Unable to sync register 0x7f0800. -5
```

---

I had a similar issue previously, but it was caused by a graphics driver update. I checked `history.log` and all of the listed updates were from Oct 12 and the issue started on Oct 15, so it doesn't appear to be caused by a driver update.

After looking at [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=269058) post, I tried disabling power saving, but that didn't have any effect.

I looked at kernel.log for the instance where this started and compared it to previous instances. It shows the the same messages as above, but there wasn't anything else that stood out.

At this point the last thing I can think of is reinstalling Ubuntu, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

**Note:** The built in audio hasn't been working since I replaced the LCD display and hinges. Audio still works when using bluetooth and the 3.5mm audio jack, so I don't care about fixing the driver as long as it will resume after a suspend.

Comment: sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/disablePower.conf

and add the line:
options snd_hda_intel power_save=0 # and then reboot.

Comment: @AndrewKrizhanovsky That worked. Thanks!